# How to get `run_id` when using MLflow Project

Tags: mlflow

When using MLflow Projects (via an `MLproject` file) I get this message at starting time:

```
INFO mlflow.projects.backend.local: 
=== Running command 'source /anaconda3/bin/../etc/profile.d/conda.sh && 
conda activate mlflow-4736797b8261ec1b3ab764c5060cae268b4c8ffa 1>&2 && 
python3 main.py' in run with ID 'e2f0e8c670114c5887963cd6a1ac30f9' ===
```

I want to access the `run_id` shown above (**e2f0e8c670114c5887963cd6a1ac30f9**) from inside the main script.

I expected a run to be active but:

```
mlflow.active_run()
> None
```

Initiating a run inside the main script does give me access the correct `run_id`, although any subsequent runs will have a different `run_id`.

```
# first run inside the script - correct run_id
with mlflow.start_run():
   print(mlflow.active_run().info.run_id)
> e2f0e8c670114c5887963cd6a1ac30f9

# second run inside the script - wrong run_id
with mlflow.start_run():
   print(mlflow.active_run().info.run_id)
> 417065241f1946b98a4abfdd920239b1
```

Seems like a strange behavior, and I was wondering if there's another way to access the `run_id` assigned at the beginning of the `MLproject` run?

Comment: Every run will have a new id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with mlflow.start_run() as run: print(run.info.run_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

to access any run anytime, you should specify the run_id like this:

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_id):
```